# AngularJS - How is a directive tied to a specific controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand the concept of isolated scope and am confused as to how a directive gets bound to a specific controller.

I've got a very simple controller and directive.  These don't appear to be related in any way.

```
myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope,  $routeParams){
    //do stuff here
}]);//end secondController

myApp.directive("searchResult", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/searchresult.html',
        replace: true
    }
});
```

Simple HTML to output a result:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <search-result></search-result>
</div>
```

Comment: the directive you have supplied doesn't have a controller, nor does it have an isolated scope.  Your question is about concepts that don't apply here.

Comment: it is *possible* that an `ng-controller` tag was added in the template file, but this is not generally good form.  It also wouldn't cause an isolated scope to be present; instead, that controller would be a child of the controller on the view the directive is provided in.